# Rotating an image with a swipe

Tags: java, android, swipe, image-rotation

I am making a new app, and I wanted to implement and in it I want a feature where you can rotate an image with the swipe of a finger. I have searched around a lot and have not found anything. If anyone has even just a hint in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: looks like a duplicate to me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758365/android-how-to-rotate-a-view-with-one-finger also... you have 2 fingers as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682019/android-two-finger-rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need use [ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) in Android.

Please check this blog post http://www.programering.com/a/MDMxEDNwATE.html