# Android: Rotate Imageview with Finger-Movement

Tags: android, button, rotation, android-imageview, touch-event

I'd like to rotate an Imageview clockwise according to the Finger-Movement for a Custom-Temperature-Button, but I have absolutely no Idea how to to handle that problem.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/temperatureBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rotation="-100"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/change_temperature_button"/>
```

I hope, you can help me out here.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please search before asking question: [Android: How to rotate a view with one finger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20758365/295004)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate the image by touching then you can implement android gestures.
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector